# Finding the risk attitude parameter in a CPT Risk Elicitation Model

Tags: risk, probability, risk-aversion

I'm working with [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11238-017-9616-x) by Bauermeister et al. that compares the risk attitude parameters found using two different risk elicitation models. The models each use a series of gambling options to determine at what point the subject is indifferent between the control game and the variable game, which increases the pay out at a fixed low probability (i.e. the control game is 40 at 30% and 20 at 70% and the variable game has increasing payout at fixed 10% and fixed payout 5 at 90%). Once this indifference point is identified, that should yield the risk attitude parameter $\alpha$ and the probability weighting factor $\lambda$. But I'm confused about how to solve for these variables.

Given in Bauermeister:
$$ U({x}_{1},p,{x}_{2},1-p) = w(p)v({x}_{1})+(1-w(p))v({x}_{2})
$$
where ${x}_{1} \geq {x}_{2} \geq 0$, and with $p \in (0,1)$
$$ v(x) = {x}^{\alpha} \\
w(p) = exp[-{(-ln(p))}^{\gamma}]
$$

Now if we find indifference between the games
$$ p{x}_{1} \text{ or } (1-p){x}_{2} \\
p'{x}_{3} \text{ or } (1-p'){x}_{4}
$$

how do we solve for $\lambda$ and $\alpha$?

Other supporting papers include:
[Abdelloui (2000)](https://www-jstor-org.proxy-bc.researchport.umd.edu/stable/2661664?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)
[Tanaka (2010)](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/22275/1/aer.100.1.557%5B1%5D.pdf)
[Wakker and Deneffe (1996)](https://repub.eur.nl/pub/23096/Eliciting_1996.pdf)